What is this movie about a human that ends up in a alien world?
When I was really young I watched a movie and I wanna know what it's called... here is what I remember:

It was about a human going to an alien planet and having to find his rocket to go home
The movie was animated in 3D style 
I am not sure but I think the alien planet in the movie looked like earth but with rings around it a bit like Saturn 
I don't think this is the year it was made but I think I watched it in 2009,2010 or 2011 I can't remember what exact year 
I think it's rated G or PG 
I can't remember if I watched it on TV or a DVD 
The aliens were green
Sadly I can't remember any characters names or any more on how they looked like
I think at the start of the movie a song was playing and it was raining rocks
The aliens were not ugly looking they were friendly/cartoon looking 


Like the animation thats used that makes the characters and everything else 3dish (like how to train your dragon or zootopia animation style) I just forgot what it was called

Could that be Planet 51 (2009) ?

An alien civilization is invaded by Astronaut Chuck Baker, who
  believes that the planet was uninhabited. Wanted by the military,
  Baker must get back to his ship before it goes into orbit without him.


